# Ebay item price list from low to high value

Tags: python-3.x, sorting, beautifulsoup, ebay-api

Currently I'm working on a project where I've to view the price of an item in eBay from low to high. How do I do that?

I'm getting the price perfectly but not in a sorted order

Here's my code's snippet:

```
from ebaysdk.finding import Connection as finder
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
keywords=input("enter keywords")
api=finder(appid='Mahxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',config_file=None)
api_req={'keywords':keywords,'outputSelector':'SellerInfo'}
response=api.execute('findItemsByKeywords',api_req)
soup=BeautifulSoup(response.content,'lxml')
total=int(soup.find('totalentries').text)
items=soup.find_all('item')
for i in items:
cat=i.categoryname.string.lower()
title=i.title.string.lower()
price=int(round(float(i.currentprice.string)))
seller=i.sellerusername.text.lower()
list=i.listingtype.string.lower()
url=i.viewitemurl.string.lower()

print("----------------------------------------")

print(title)
print(price)
print(seller)
print(url)
```

Here's the output I'm getting:

```
apple iphone x 64gb 256gb at&t sprint unlocked us cellular verizon
856
alltechwholesale
----------------------------------------
apple iphone x 64gb 256gb space gray silver (unlocked) at&t - t-mobile - sprint
919
iphones.tested.trusted
----------------------------------------
apple iphone x - 256gb - silver (at&t) a1901 (gsm)
875
abooghait
```

Comment: If you add the piece of code that scrapes the page, maybe we can help you better. Also, why not sort it at your end?

Comment: All right I'll upload and I've a question. Should I put the price on a list and sort it out at end ?

Comment: @ManasJayanth updated

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to sort it yourself afterwards, but of course you can if you like.

You're using the eBay API, specifically the Finding API, and more specifically, the call 'findItemsByKeywords'. Therefore, you have access to a plethora of filters and sorting options. [On this page](https://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/finding/CallRef/types/SortOrderType.html) are the sort orders you can use, including some pricing sorts.

I'm not familiar with the language or SDK you are using, but somehow you'll need to insert code for specifying the sort.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm using the 'findItemsByKeywords' and I wanna use 'CurrentPriceHighest' for the sorting order. But I'm not sure how to use it. Can you please explain ? 
PS : I'm using Python3, ebaySDK and BeautifulSoup